# How to point a domain registered with ENS to IPFS content?

Tags: ipfs, ens, dns, eth-domain

After securing a `.eth` domain, how do you point the domain to resolve to an IPFS hash?

Answer (score 4):

Turns out to be very simple:

1. Visit https://manager.ens.domains/
2. Search your `.eth` domain
3. Click the `Resolver Details` tab
4. Paste your `IPFS` content hash into the `Set Content` input
5. Send the transaction out `!Be careful:` to set the Gas fee, the default is too low

Comment: ⚠️ The Set Content feature appears to be associating the [wrong IPFS hash](https://github.com/ensdomains/ens-manager/issues/45) with the domain, I will update once a solution is found

Answer (score 1):

Look Up dnsLink

dnslink.io has some newer write-ups on it. One way is to edit the Cname of A Dns Record for a domain you own Godaddy has two main fields for this

"Host" fill this field in with "api" (could be anything but this is self describing)

next you need to point the Sub domain at gateway.ipfs.io

set the TTL (how long between calls to something around 600 seconds or less so that any mistakes can be quickly patched.

Lastly you want to fill out the TXT Record:

_dnslink goes in the first area.

next we type

dnslink=/ipfs/dnslink/

you can replace the content hash with a more permanent Peer Id if the content is likely to change.

your Ipfs content is now linked to a domain name. The ENS name should be able to do the same, I think it comes down to being able to efficiently scrape the record off of the ENS name server ( maybe a webhook, or some kind of bot to publish changes to the Records of the Ens subdomain name's page. Good Luck for now, it's late, If you have any issues I will try to be here to help, GOOD luck and let me know how it goes (Good Or Bad)

This Walk Through is the best one I came across (and I looked for a long time)

https://medium.com/textileio/the-definitive-guide-to-publishing-content-on-ipfs-ipns-dfe751f1e8d0